# Prove that $(\cot A+\cot B)(\cot B+\cot C)(\cot A+\cot C)=\csc A\csc B\csc C$

Tags: trigonometry

I was trying to find the value of $(\cot A+\cot B)(\cot B+\cot C)(\cot A+\cot C)$, given that $A+B+C=\pi$.

I tried using the identity $\cot A+\cot B+\cot C=-\cot A\cot B\cot C$ (It can be easily derived), if $A+B+C=\pi$. But it doesn't help much, and I am stuck now. I know the answer should be $cosecAcosecBcosecC$(this I verified by simply substituting angles and checking which combination of T-ratios gives the same answer). Please help.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$\cot A+\cot B=\dfrac{\sin(B+A)}{\sin A\sin B}=\dfrac{\sin(\pi-C)}{\sin A\sin B}=?$$

Comment: Thanks a lot @labbhattacharjee.......i should have converted to sine-cosine format.....I cannot accept the answer for another 9 minutes, I'll do it once the warning thing goes

Answer (score 2):

Notice, in $\triangle ABC$, $A+B+C=\pi=180^\circ$

Now, we have $$LHS=(\cot A+\cot B)(\cot B+\cot C)(\cot C+\cot A)$$
$$=\left(\frac{\cos A}{\sin A}+\frac{\cos B}{\sin B}\right)\left(\frac{\cos B}{\sin B}+\frac{\cos C}{\sin C}\right)\left(\frac{\cos C}{\sin C}+\frac{\cos A}{\sin A}\right)$$
$$=\left(\frac{\sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B}{\sin A\sin B}\right)\left(\frac{\sin B\cos C+\cos B\sin C}{\sin B\sin C}\right)\left(\frac{\sin C\cos A+\cos C\sin A}{\sin C\sin A}\right)$$
$$=\left(\frac{\sin(A+B)}{\sin A\sin B}\right)\left(\frac{\sin(B+C)}{\sin B\sin C}\right)\left(\frac{\sin(C+A)}{\sin C\sin A}\right)$$
$$=\left(\frac{\sin(180^\circ-C)}{\sin A\sin B}\right)\left(\frac{\sin(180^\circ-A)}{\sin B\sin C}\right)\left(\frac{\sin(180^\circ-B)}{\sin C\sin A}\right)$$
$$=\left(\frac{\sin C}{\sin A\sin B}\right)\left(\frac{\sin A}{\sin B\sin C}\right)\left(\frac{\sin B}{\sin C\sin A}\right)$$ $$=\frac{1}{\sin A\sin B\sin C}$$ $$=cosec A cosec B cesec C=RHS$$

Comment: thanks a lot@HarishChandraRajpoot.....but I already accepted @labbhattacharjee's answer(they are the same though)..upvote though